# Window Focus Event Not Firing on IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have a handler that I use to detect when a user has focused the window, this works perfectly on Chrome but the event is not firing on IE11.

The event handler looks like: `window.addEventListener('focus', this.doSomething);`

Is there an IE11 equivalent of the above?

I have tried `focusin` but the behaviour is different and breaks my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it worked on both Chrome and IE11:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    alert("focused")
})
```

Would you pls post your code?